# how to organize all JQuery scripts

Tags: jquery

i am using half dozen jquery plugins and plus my own jquery scripts and in every script i have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ .... }
```

what is the best way of organizing all the scripts in one centeralized location and instead of having multiple times **$(document).ready(function()** everywhere in the script.

thoughts?

**UPDATE**

one.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
$("#aspnetForm").validate({
rules: 
{
<%=txtVisitName.UniqueID %>: 
 {
      maxlength:1, 
       required: true
  },
 deleted lines......
```

two.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(event) { 
    if ($("#aspnetForm").valid())
        SaveVisitBasicPage();
     deleted lines......
```

three.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function initMenu() {
    $('#menu ul').hide();
    $('#menu li a').click(
     deleted lines......
```

four.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#ctl00_cphMaster_txtPurpose").NobleCount('#count01',
{ 
    max_chars: 25,
    on_negative: 'go_red',
    on_positive: 'go_green',
    block_negative: true                     
    deleted lines......
```

how would i organize the above .js files?, you see above having mulitple times $(document).ready(function().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) dependency management framework?

Answer (score 2):

Pack all of your functions into an object, which you can chain between files by attaching it to window. Then pass an anonymous function that kicks off all of your DOM-dependent events in a doc ready.

example:

file1

```
var MyObj = {
     init: function(){
     // do stuff
     },
     otherStuff: function(){
     // do other stuff
     }
}

window.MyObj = MyObj
```

file2

```
var MyObj = window.MyObj;

MyObj.moreStuff = function(){
     //do more stuff
}

$(document).ready(function(){
     MyObj.init();
     MyObj.moreStuff();
})
```

You should only have one document.ready() executing per pageload. Or else you're doing it wrong.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have updated my question, how would i go organizing files?,.. i am not clear with your sample code. appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help, but this is how I organize my jQuery scripts. Our application has 80K lines of JavaScript, so organization is important, and this has worked for us nicely.

[Self Executing Function pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188663/jquery-javascript-design-self-executing-function-or-object-literal)

Comment: I should point out that you should scroll down in that question to the answer I posted.