# Can I run a JavaScript function AFTER Google Loader has run?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I am loading Google API using `google.load()` and I need to process some of what is built by it, but I need to run the JavaScript after it has already completely loaded, is there a way to ensure that happens?

Here is how I build the list of images, I need to add an attribute to each `img` tag though, can't do that until after it is built right?

```
google.load("feeds", "1");

function initialize() {
    var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("myfeed.rss");

    feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {             

            var container = document.getElementById("feed");

            for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {               

               var entry = result.feed.entries[i];

               var entryTitle = entry.title;
               var entryContent = entry.content;

               imgContent = entryContent + "<p>"+entryTitle+"</p>";

               var div = document.createElement("div");
               div.className = "image";               

               div.innerHTML = imgContent;

               container.appendChild(div);
           }
       }
   });
}

google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this is by creating an anonymous function in the `setOnLoadCallback`like so:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){

    //Run the Initialize Function
    initialize(function(){
         //Run anything else here like
         alert("My function can run here :)")  
    });
});
```

and then just modify your initialize function.

f`unction initialize() {` > `function initialize(callback) {` so that you no are passing in an anonymous function to the intialize.

and then within the `feed.load(function(result) {});`  you can just do `callback()` to activate your callback.

---

you say that anonymous function confuses you, Let me first show you a few ways to write a function

- `function hello(){}`
- `hello = function(){}`

The above are non-anonymous functions

Anonymous functions are functions that are not assigned to a variable, so the parser goes over the function and does not execute it

```
alert("Start")
function()
{
    alert("Middle")
}
alert("End");
```

Running the above will show Start and End in a dialog but Middle will never show as the function has not been executed.

Function the following:

```
( F )( P )
```

Where F is an anonymous function and P Is the param that should be in the scope, you can directly run anonymous functions without ever assigning to the function to a variable liek so:

```
alert("Start")
(
    function(Doc){
        alert("Middle");
    }
)(document)
alert("End")
```

So `document` gets passed into the anonymous function and becomes Doc in that scope, and Start, Middle and End all will get executed as your using a [self executed anonymous function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188663/jquery-javascript-design-self-executing-function-or-object-literal)

Ok so I might have gone over the top with the explanation so ill just quickly show you how the original method works

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Ajax is Asynchronously which means that when your calling a server such as google for some information, your javascript will continue to execute which means while your waiting for data your javscript has carried on executing..

This is why we devoted callbacks just like the `initialize` callback, which the google Javascript library executes when its got the data, when have create our own and were executing when we want to.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that worked great.  Though I would like to understand why it works more if you don't mind :)  The anonymous function part confuses me.. lol

Comment: Awesome man, thanks a ton. I have used them before, but did not know exactly what it was doing.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/#GoogleLoad) specifies that you can include a callback function in the third parameter of the `google.load()` method.

Something like this should work:

```
google.load("jquery", "1.4.2", {
    callback: function() {
        alert('Finished!');
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that is just a callback for once it has finished loading though. I had tried that and the function does not operate on the resulting list that is created.

Comment: I thought you were wanting a callback once the loader finished loading something? Perhaps posting some of what you have right now will help me understand what you're needing...

Comment: I added code to the original post, hope it helps make more sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Great. Try removing google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize); Is your initialize event not being called? It looks like you have everything set up correctly...

Comment: Remove that and keep my custom callback in there? I did and nothing happened at all.  But the initialize runs yes, the list is built perfect as I would expect it to..