# Using Anonymous function for google feed api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api

I saw a similar post to this, so I tried to follow the answer of that question but it didn't work. Where is my mistake? I think it should display "My function can run here :)". But both RSS feeds and this alert dont appear.

```
    google.load("feeds", "1");
function initialize(callback) {
  var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://www.ntvmsnbc.com/id/24927681/device/rss/rss.xml");
  feed.setNumEntries(6);

  feed.load(function(result) {}){
    if (!result.error) {
      var container = document.getElementById("feed");
      var html = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
        var a= " ";
        a += entry.title;
        info[i] = a;
        callback();
       html += '<p>' + entry.publishedDate + '&nbsp' + entry.title;
      }
      container.innerHTML = html;
    }
  });
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){

//Run the Initialize Function
initialize(function(){
     //Run anything else here like
     alert("My function can run here :)")  
});
});
```

Ok I'm updating my question =). Instead of this alert, can I add entry.title into an array in this function? If yes, what should I write there

Comment: this is where I got the example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572959/can-i-run-a-javascript-function-after-google-loader-has-run

Comment: feed.load(function(result) {}){  //should be just: feed.load(function(result)){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've mixed up some syntax:

```
feed.load(function(result) {}){
```

should be

```
feed.load(function(result){
```

Comment: So this was indeed the fix? or...?

Comment: actually I created a global array. I want to add entr.titles into this array. I heard that I should use anonymous function. So I don't know what should I write inside initialize(function(){}). Do you have any idea?